# WSO2 Stream Processor SQL Server connection

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm pretty new to WSO2 SP, and trying to read data from a SQL Server DB using the tutorial [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Integrating+Datastores). But unfortunately, I'm not able to make a connection to the SQL Server database, to move further.

I've placed the latest [JDBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=11774) in lib folder.

```
@App:name('MyTestApp')

@source(type = 'http', @map(type = 'json'))
define stream RawMaterialStream(name string, username string, empid string);

@primaryKey('empid')
@index('name')
@store(type='rdbms', jdbc.url="jdbc:sqlserver://<servername>:1433;databaseName=ACL", username="<username>", password="<password>",jdbc.driver.name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
define table EmpDetails(name string, username string, empid string);

from RawMaterialStream
select name, username, empid
update or insert into EmpDetails
on EmpDetails.name == name;
```

These are the errors received during execution:

> [2019-03-20_20-19-56_912] ERROR {com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf} - Exception setting property driverClassName on target class com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> [2019-03-20_20-19-56_913] ERROR {org.wso2.siddhi.core.table.Table} - Error on 'MyTestApp'. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException . Error while connecting to Table 'EmpDetails'. (Encoded)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Can anyone please help/advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the MSSQL JDBC driver is not OSGified. As drivers need to be OSGified to be recognised by SP.

You can convert to OSGi bundle using the following command in /bin

> ./jartobundle.sh  ../lib

Please see following [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP4xx/Adding+Third+Party+Non+OSGi+Libraries) for more details.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was exactly the issue and has been rectified.